# import data from bloomberg to r

Tags: r, bloomberg

I am trying to import historical data from Bloomberg to R for a specific field & list of securities. I created list of securities in bloomberg EQS function. What function should I use in R to put list of securities? (I have 3000 securities)

```
library("Rblpapi")
bdh(securities, fields, start.date, end.date=NULL, include.non.trading.days=FALSE, 
    options=NULL, overrides=NULL,  verbose=FALSE, identity=NULL, con=defaultConnection(),  
    int.as.double=getOption("blpIntAsDouble", FALSE))
```

Comment: Hi, please always specify the libraries you used which in this case is probably `library(Rblpapi)`, and format your code nicer. This time I've helped you.

Comment: Could you add an abbreviated example of the code how you created the list to your question please?

Comment: thank you, actually i am pretty new to R, and i am trying to figure out what code i should use, but my main issue is the first step on inserting the securities: bdh(securities,)  i have 3000 tickers which i created a portfolio in EQS function in bloomberg, how should i put them in this basic R function?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what you want to do without a smaller repeatable example, but I think what you need to do is assign the securities to a variable.  See example below.  In this case, your securities are equivalent to my tickers variable below.

```
    # Load package
    library(Rblpapi)

    # Connect to Bloomberg
    blpConnect()

    # Assign tickers and fields
    tickers <- c("SPX INDEX", "IBM EQUITY")
    myField <- "PX_LAST"

    # Pull Bloomberg data and create data frame
        stock_prices <- as.data.frame(
            bdh(tickers,
                myField,
                start.date = as.Date("2019-05-01"),
                end.date   = as.Date("2019-05-20"),
                include.non.trading.days = TRUE)
                )
```